# Filter different variables based on different conditions

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

I have a deep nested data and a function that runs on it through purrr. Here is a mock data & analysis that resembles my case:

```
df <- tibble::tribble(
     ~A, ~B, ~C,
    "e", 2L, 6L,
    "e", 5L, 8L,
    "e", 5L, 3L,
    "f", 3L, 8L,
    "f", 4L, 1L,
    "f", 5L, 6L,
    "g", 3L, 9L,
    "g", 4L, 2L,
    "g", 5L, 7L,
    "h", 5L, 4L
    )
```

I need to filter different variables based on different conditions. I need to do something like this:

```
df1 <- df %>% group_by(A) %>% 
              nest() %>% 
              case_when(A == "e" ~filter(B<4),
              A == "f" ~filter(C<=6),
              A == "g" ~filter(B<5, C<7))
```

My desired output should be:

```
desired_output <- tibble::tribble(
                     ~A, ~B, ~C,
                    "e", 2L, 6L,
                    "f", 4L, 1L,
                    "f", 5L, 6L,
                    "g", 4L, 2L
                    )
```

Comment: Please see my post. We have different output. I believe it is probably because you missed some condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option can be as:

```
df1 <- df %>% group_by(A) %>% 
  mutate(filterV = case_when(
    A == "e" ~ (B<4),
    A == "f" ~ (C<=6),
    A == "g" ~ (B<5 & C<7))) %>%
  filter(filterV) %>%
  select(-filterV)

df1
# # A tibble: 4 x 3
# # Groups: A [3]
#   A         B     C
#  <chr> <int> <int>
# 1 e         2     6
# 2 f         4     1
# 3 f         5     6
# 4 g         4     2
```

Comment: Good. We have the same result. I am thinking the OP may miss some conditions to specify.

Comment: @www That;s true. I thought our result is matching with that of OP but its not.

Comment: @www I manually checked values. Our result matches description in question.

Comment: Thanks for doing that. I guess OP has some requirements for the column C. But even that, OP can probably modify our solutions for that without too much difficulty.

Comment: yeah, you are right, my mistake. My conditions were: df1 %>% case_when(A == "e" ~filter(B<4),
                  A == "f" ~filter(C<=6),
                  A == "g" ~filter(B<5, C<7))   I have edited that in the main question.

Comment: @Geet Fine. We'll sort out our answer in that way so that future users will not be confused.

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer MKR! @www Glad to have two ways to solve the filtering problem.

Answer (score 4):

We can do the following to filter for different conditions.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  filter((A %in% "e" & B < 4)  | 
           (A %in% "f" & C <= 6) |
           (A %in% "g" & B < 5 & C < 7))  
# # A tibble: 4 x 3
#   A         B     C
#   <chr> <int> <int>
# 1 e         2     6
# 2 f         4     1
# 3 f         5     6
# 4 g         4     2
```